# Ruby Error: Not Finding Variable Defined in Loop

Tags: ruby, loops, variables, scope, undefined

I have code in Ruby that defines a variable in a loop.

```
print("What difficulty do you want on a scale of 1-5?\n")
loop do
  difficulty = gets.to_i
  break if difficulty == 1 or difficulty == 2 or difficulty == 3 or difficulty == 4 or difficulty == 5
end
range = 10 if difficulty == 1
range = 100 if difficulty == 2
range = 500 if difficulty == 3
range = 1000 if difficulty == 4
range = 5000 if difficulty == 5
```

I get an error that the variable *difficulty* is undefined. I think this is an issue from the loop. and I do not know how to implement it into another form that would serve the same purpose. Is there a way that I could make the variable global? I have tried looking up other ways to make it in another format but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it outside the loop otherwise, it'd be scope-constrained.

Try:

```
difficulty_range = {
  1 => 10,
  2 => 100,
  3 => 500,
  4 => 1000,
  5 => 5000
}

difficulty = nil

loop do
  print("What difficulty do you want on a scale of 1-5?\n")
  difficulty = gets.to_i
  break if (1..5).include?(difficulty)
end

p difficulty_range[difficulty]
```